# Snipmatch Code Recommender plugin does not work for custom repository

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, code-snippets

I just created a repository to share our team snippets, and although everyone can see, update, and push new snippets, none of them appear on the Java Editor auto complete.

[image: Example for arrayremove]

For testing purposes I created a new snippet (arrayremove) copying the configuration from an existing one (arraymerge).

[image: Comparison]

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something? Or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick Answer**

You have to press `CTRL+ALT+SPACE` to start the Snipmatch snippet search. Snipmatch snippets will not appear in the normal content assist popup.

**Background**

As one of the developers of the Code Recommenders Snipmatch plugin, let me give you a little bit of background information.

Snipmatch uses a separate shortcut to trigger a search to allow more intelligent snippet searches. For example, the search string may contain spaces and will find keywords defined as an *Extra Search Term* or as a *Tag*. Or you can use wildcards `*` in your search string.

You can change the shortcut on the *Preferences > General > Keys* preference page. Look for the *Snipmatch Snippet Completion* binding.

For more information, have a look at the [Snipmatch manual](https://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/manual/#snipmatch).

if you need further support with Snipmatch, you can also contact me directly or go to the [Code Recommenders forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/211/).